# How to run haskell code that's passed via command argument to the interpreter?

Tags: haskell, stdin

Among other methods, there are a few most common ways to run a haskell program:

- `ghci`, load the file, run main by hand from shell
- `runhaskell file.hs`
- `ghc file.hs && ./file`

I weren't able to find, however, how to run simple code from standard input / command arguments.

For example, standard Lua interpreter will allow you to do:

```
$ lua -e "print (2+2)"
4
```

What would be an equivalent of the above for a common Haskell Platform environment?

Comment: Would the downvoter please state the reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just the same.

```
$ ghc -e "print (2+2)"
4
```

Comment: Now I feel a bit dumb, but that answer is a surprising food for thought about more Lua and Haskell similiarities.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It's not really Lua and Haskell similarities. More or less every compiler/interpreter has an interface like that on unixy systems. It's just a convention.